# Android listvitem AsyncTask listitem image dereference

Tags: android, listitem

I am using listview to display data, inside listview i am using image in every listeitem.

following method is called from wrapper class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {  /*implementation*/ }
```

I am following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html

```
class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Drawable>{
        private ImageView iv;

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(ImageView... params) {
            iv = params[0];
            return Util.getImageFromURL(imageURL); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( Drawable d ) {
            iv.setImageDrawable(d);
        }

}
new DownloadImage().execute(getImageIcon());
```

getImageIcon contains the reference of the inflater layout's imageview.

Now problem is first when 2nd listeitem image gets loaded it also resplaces the first listeitem image and so on...

i think it is listitem's referencing issue but above code should work b/c i am passing imageview reference inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview/) may provide some guidance on using images with ListViews.

---

**EDIT**: Since @Hunt has pointed out the above link is dead, here's a great one that is in the official Android developer docs:

- [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/) → [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) → [Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html) → [Load Bitmaps into a GridView Implementation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#gridview)